# error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token

Tags: c++, cloud9-ide

First time in a computer science class. First lab assignment. Wrote exactly what the teacher wrote, yet it wont compile, and neither the teacher or I can figure out why. Please help. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int number;
string residence;
//Just an example of a comment
cout << "Hello. Welcome to CSCI-1!" endl;
cout << "Spring 2014" endl;

cout << "please enter a number: " endl;
cin >> number;

cout << "you entered the number: " << number <<endl;

cout<<"Please enter your state of residence: " endl;
cin>>residence;
cout <<"you stated you live in " << residence <<"." <<;
return 0;
}
```

Errors:

lab01.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

lab01.cpp:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’

lab01.cpp:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’

lab01.cpp:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’

lab01.cpp:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘endl’

lab01.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token

Comment: Missing "<<" before "endl".

Comment: If your teacher can't spot what's wrong here, I'd be really worried.

Comment: Yea, our teacher is a math teacher, and I think it's his first time teaching csci.

Comment: You should complain to your college for assigning a maths teacher to teach a subject he knows nothing about - just about anyone who has progressed beyond beginner status would instantly be able to interpret those errors.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `<<` operator before the `endl` constructs.  Change

```
cout << "Hello. Welcome to CSCI-1!" endl;
```

To

```
cout << "Hello. Welcome to CSCI-1!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the missing `<<` before `endl` (in several lines), you also have an extra one on a line:

```
cout <<"you stated you live in " << residence <<"." <<;
                                                    ^^ -- extra!
```

This will cause you to get another compiler error once you fix the first one.  It should be:

```
cout <<"you stated you live in " << residence <<"." << endl;
```

or

```
cout <<"you stated you live in " << residence <<".";
```